# overflow : scroll in a div containing dynamic ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overflow

i'm developping an API using angular4, ccs3 and jquery 3.3.1. I want my code to load a json file  whitch contains information about some projects and i want my scripts to load into the HTML file the  risk and alertes about per projects into my component app-details and precisely in my div with class="scroll". this div contain an ul.

**What I tried so far:**

I put my overflow : auto property into my .scroll with height 35% of my body size. Put this don't work. i also use overflow-y auto and overflow-y: scroll to make test. But, my scroll don't work correctly. It show itself but it hide my script content result (after ligne 36). I also use scrollTop but don't work. i' also try to use the absolute position and reduce my margin and padding but none of them work.

i'm using Chrome to make my developing.

```js
var sujetCourant;
var url = "../assets/data/data.json";
var idEltCourant= 0;
var risques2= " Le(s) Risque(s) sur ce(s) projet(s)";
var attentes2 = "Le(s) Attente(s) sur ce(s) projets(s)";
var scroll= $('div.scroll'),
$scrollTo =$('div.scroll');

$(document.getElementsByClassName('.scroll')).ready(function(){
    //on charge le fichier json
     $.getJSON(url, function (data){
      var nbRisqueSujetCourant = 0;
      var nbAttenteSujetCourant = 0;
      //je recupère la position de ma element section  
       
     //on parcours le fichier tant que la fin n'est pas atteinte
       while( idEltCourant < data.projets.length){ 
         //recuperation du nom du sujet courant
         sujetCourant = data.projets[idEltCourant].titre;
        //recuperation  du nombre d'attentes ou alertes du sujet courant
        nbAttenteSujetCourant = data.projets[idEltCourant].attentes[0].nbattente;
         //recuperation du nombres de risques du sujet courant;
         nbRisqueSujetCourant = data.projets[idEltCourant].risques[0].nbrisques;
        
         // affichage suivant le nombre de risques ou d'alertes par SUJETS.
         // si le sujet courant n'a ni d'alertes ni de risques on passe au sujets suivant sans traitements
          if (nbAttenteSujetCourant == 0 && nbRisqueSujetCourant  == 0 ) {
       
              
            idEltCourant =idEltCourant +1;
           } 
        // cas ou le sujet n'a pas de risques on affiche seulement les attentes
         // Affichage en couleur Rouge les attentes
        else if(nbAttenteSujetCourant != 0 && nbRisqueSujetCourant  == 0) {          
           //Afichage du nom du projet
           $('ul.resultatdetails').css('color','#00008B').css('padding-left','10%').css('padding-bottom','3%').text( sujetCourant).css('padding-top', '0%');
          
          //affichage du titre Attente(s)
          $('ul.contenuattentes').css('padding-left','10%').text(attentes2).css('padding-top', '3%').css('color', '#000000');
         // on fera une boucle qui affichera par ligne une liste d'attentes
  //       //  for( var attentecourant= 0; attentecourant<nbAttenteSujetCourant; attentecourant++){
       
  //       //  }
  //        console.log(sujetCourant);
  //       // console.log('------------------------------');
  //       // console.log(nbAttenteSujetCourant);
          
        idEltCourant =idEltCourant +1;
  //       }
  
  //       // affichage en jaune
  //       else if(nbAttenteSujetCourant == 0 && nbRisqueSujetCourant  != 0){
  //         $('ul.resultatdetails').css('color','#00008B').css('padding-left','7%').css('padding-bottom', '3%').text( sujetCourant).css('padding-top', '3%');
  //       /*   console.log(sujetCourant);
  //         console.log('------------------------------');
  //         console.log(nbAttenteSujetCourant);
  
  //         console.log('------------------------------');
  //         console.log(nbRisqueSujetCourant);
  //         console.log('------------------------------'); */
  //         idEltCourant =idEltCourant +1;
  //       }
  //       else{
  //         $('ul.resultatdetails').css('color','#00008B').css('padding-left','7%').css('padding-bottom', '3%').text( sujetCourant).css('padding-top', '3%');
  //         // console.log(sujetCourant);
  //         // console.log('------------------------------');
  //         // console.log(nbAttenteSujetCourant);
  
  //         // console.log('------------------------------');
  //         // console.log(nbRisqueSujetCourant);
  //         // console.log('------------------------------');
         // idEltCourant =idEltCourant +1;
        }
    idEltCourant =idEltCourant +1;
       
      }
    console.log(data.projets.length);
  });
  
});
```

```css
#details {
    margin-top: -5%;
    background-color: floralwhite;    
    padding-left: 3%;
    color: black;  
    height: 15%; 
    font-size: 180%;    
}
#p {
    padding-top: 2%;
    height: 100%;
    }
.resultatdetails{
    background-color: floralwhite;
    margin-top: -1%;
    margin-bottom: -1.7%;
    font-size: 120%;
    font-style:  italic;
    height: 70%;
    width: 90%;  
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-top: 0.2%;
    text-align: left;  
    list-style:none;


}

.scroll{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 4.5%;
    margin-right: 3.5%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    font-family: Verdana, Fantasy, Trebuchet MS, normal, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    width:  53.5%;
    height: 98% relative;
    border-style:groove;
    border-color: black;
    border-style:10% groove;
    overflow-y: scroll;

    position: absolute;
   
}

.detailsrouge{
    color: red;
    min-height: 40%;
}

.detailsjaune{
    color: gold;
   min-height: 40%;
}
.contenurisques, .contenuattentes{
    list-style:none;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    padding-top: 1.5%;  
    font-size: 100%; 
    overflow-y: inherit;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: absolute;

}
```

```html
  <div class="scroll"> 
  <article id="details">
    <p id="p">Détail des risques et attentes d'arbitrage.</p>
  </article>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>

  <ul class="resultatdetails">
    <ul class="contenuattentes" >
      <ul class="detailsrouge">
        
        
      </ul>
    </ul>
    <ul class="contenurisques">
      <ul class="detailsjaune">
              
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </ul>    

</div>
```

My result here:

Comment: Why do you have nested `ul`'s?

Comment: you should structure it more towards: `<ul><li><ul></ul></li></ul>`

Comment: only `li` can be a child of `ul`

Comment: i want my result to be like this  Project 1:  risk : risk 1 to risk n. alert: alert 1 to alert n; The same presentation for all my project

Comment: hanyatou to get that you need to nest your sub `ul`s *within* a `li` (as per @rileyjsumner 's comment)

Comment: ok, thanks. it is done. I have this one now  <ul class="resultatdetails">
    <li class="contenuattentes" >
      <ul class="detailsrouge">
        
        
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="contenurisques">
      <ul class="detailsjaune">
              
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

Comment: this change does not change my problem, the result is the same

Comment: I finally solve my problem. thanks